# Writing a library in a framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a little problem concerning writing a library. I am currently tasked with writing said library, but on the .Net Framework 4.6.2. When trying to chose a target framework in Visual Studio 2019, it only offers me the .Net Core libraries. My boss however is telling me to specifically write for the 4.6.2 .Net Framework. How do I do that? I found nothing online to that?

Comment: In general, creating a new project and copying all files over is the safest option. I have marked your question as a duplicate of another one which discusses the options available in detail.

Comment: Have you installed the .Net Framework SDK for 4.6.2?

Comment: There should be an "Class Library (.Net Framework)" option when you create a new project. You might need to adjust the installed modules with the VS installer. I would ask your boss if targeting ".Net standard" would not be better. This would make the library usable in both .Net 4.6.2 and .Net core, but there might be some special reason why it is not appropriate.

Comment: @phuzi Yeah, did all of that. Fixed it by myself, but in the end, it turns out my efforst were wasted. because I found a nuGet library that does what I want.